# Induction on well formed formula

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I need to prove in induction that -

In a (WFF) well-formed formula between every two atoms there is a connective.

1. Should my base case be about one atom or two ?
2. In my proof(Induction step) should I assume this is true for a subset of the formula?

Thanks!

Comment: It's _well-formed_, not _well-formatted_.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: I assume that these are the well-formed formulas of propositional logic. These are defined by structural recursion:

- Each atom is a WFF.
- If $\varphi$ is a WFF, so is $\neg\varphi$.
- If $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are WFFs, and $*$ is a binary connected (e.g., $\lor,\land,\to$), then $(\varphi*\psi)$ is a WFF.
- The only WFFs are those objects that are required to be WFFs on the basis of the first three points.

To prove that the family of WFFs has some property $P$, one uses structural induction; this is a kind of induction argument that parallels the recursive definition of the family of WFFs. The steps are:

- Show that each atom has the property $P$.
- Show that if a WFF $\varphi$ has $P$, then so does $\neg\varphi$.
- Show that if WFFs $\varphi$ and $\psi$ have $P$, and $*$ is one of the binary connectives, then so does $(\varphi*\psi)$ has $P$.

If you can do all this, you can conclude by (structural) induction that all WFFs have $P$.

In your particular case the first (or basis) step is easy: each atom has $P$ vacuously, because no atom contains two atoms at all. Now see if you can carry out the two parts of the induction step: both are very straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

You want to prove something for all WFFs, thus your induction should (most likely) run over all WFFs. In particular, the base case of your induction should be about the smallest WFF, which is a single atom. If you start your induction at a formula containing 2 atoms, then *technically* you haven't proved your statement for formulas with only one atom.

Induction over WFFs typically follows a recipe like this: each formula is assigned some measure of complexity, such as its length, the number of connectives, or the depth of the connectives. These measures have the following in common: if $\phi = \phi_1 \land \phi_2$, then $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ will have lower complexity than $\phi$. (And similarly for the other connectives.)

Then, your induction runs over complexity: you prove that your proposition holds for all atomic formulas (formulas of least complexity); then, you prove that it holds for an arbitrary formula $\phi$ (such as the one above) assuming that it holds for all formulas of lower complexity (usually subformulas, such as $\phi_1,\phi_2$ above).